# Change InactiveDt to be same date as the next lowest EffectiveDt from the product id

Tags: mysql, date, compare-and-swap

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE ProductPrice
(
ProductId       INT             NOT NULL,
EffectiveDt     DATE            NOT NULL,
InactiveDt      DATE            NOT NULL,
Price           DECIMAL(10,2)   NOT NULL
)
```

What I'm wanting to do is use an update so that the inactivedt of the record with the lowest effectivedt is changed to the effectivedt - 1 of record with the next lowest effectivedt for each product id.

So say we have:

```
21/07/2012  26/07/2012
24/07/2012  28/07/2012
27/07/2012  30/07/2012
```

this would be changed to:

```
21/07/2012  23/07/2012
24/07/2012  26/07/2012
27/07/2012  30/07/2012
```

So far I have:

```
UPDATE pp 
SET    pp.InactiveDt = (SELECT pe.EffectiveDt
               FROM   ProductPrice pe 
               WHERE  pe.ProductId = pp.ProductId
               ) 
FROM   ProductPrice pp;
```

but this doesn't really do what I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do it in one big update query, and even if you could, it would be a mess of a code.

The correct way to do it would be with MySQL stored procedures that allow you to write a script using for and while loops and you can invoque it whenever you want with a simple select.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html